# Find nth term of series from sum function

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I thinking to find nth term of a series if sum function of the series is given

For example
Let's say
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n T_k=\frac{n(2n^2+9n+13)}{6}$

So I can find TN by first finding like 4-5 terms of the series by $s_1,s_2-s_1,s_3-s_2,..., s_n-s_{n-1}$, where $s_k=k-$th partial sum.

Then by basic series analysis find $T_k$

but this particular series it took a bit time as there was not a particular series with patter but the common difference of the series common difference were so it took a bit time

So I was thinking it their a bit smart method to find $T_n$ easily.

Comment: 1) Your left hand side makes no sense. It should be $\sum_{\color{red}k=1}^nT_{\color{red}k}.$ 2) Hint: $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^nT_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}T_k.$ 3) What did you find for $T_n?$

Answer (score 4):

$$S_n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n T_k=\frac{n(2n^2+9n+13)}{6}$$

then, for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$,

$$T_k=S_k-S_{k-1}=$$
$$=\frac{k(2k^2+9k+13)}{6}-\frac{(k-1)(2(k-1)^2+9(k-1)+13)}{6}=$$

$$=\frac{6k^2+12k+6}{6}=(k+1)^2.$$

Comment: Well why didn't I think of this thanks